# Interpreting margin of error estimate

Tags: statistics

Take this as a thought experiment at first, although it relates to something we are doing through our nonprofit: Assume every member of a population (not a sample!) of 550,000 is asked a yes or no question. 150,000 of them respond 'yes' or 'no,' the rest don't answer. How close is this response to that of the entire population, had they all responded? At a 99% confidence level, these numbers give a margin of error of about 0.28% (I think!). Can we interpret the margin of error to mean that the proportion of yeses and noes in the data set of 150,000 voluntary responses will be within 0.28% plus or minus of the 'actual population response,' 99% percent of the time?

Comment: It is unreasonable to assume that those who do answer are representative of those who do not answer.

Comment: What was your calculation? Feel free to post it.

Comment: @Henry Isn't that assumption (given the right parameters) the foundation of inferential statistics?

Comment: @callculus42 The question is about the interpretation, not the calculation. Assuming the facts as given are true (which is why I called it a 'thought experiment') what is the interpretation? That said, I just used an online calculator.

Comment: The problem is that if people of type A are more likely to reply than people of type B, then you will overestimate the proportion of type A, and you will be over-confident in the accuracy of your results. Thus is a well-known issue in social research.

Comment: @user1209402 Maybe I'm wrong, but [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=round+2.576*sqrt%2815*40%2F55%5E2%2F150000%29*100+to+2+digits) (in percent) iss my calculation.

Comment: You'll need to implement some kind of imputation technique -- there are many -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_(statistics)